# SQL to XML for FDA HL7 guideline requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, hl7

I have a SQL that was originally/currently used to populate a PDF.
Now the FDA requires XML in a HL7 guideline format.
I am just wondering if anyone else out there has any useful links or guides to how to convert the SQL to an XML and into the format that is required.

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.
I will attempt to modify my SQL to protect company related information, and post it here so that you can see how far (or how far behind) I am.

Comment: Where can I see the Guideline?

Comment: The entire packet can be downloaded here:
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/eMDR/eMDR_HL7ICSR.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with tools specific to HL7.

In general, if you need to generate XML from a SQL Server database, I'd use SQL/XML features that let you embed XQuery statements in SQL. E.g. start with this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189928.aspx

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for.